# Schengen student visa and tourism visa

Tags: visas, schengen, international-travel, study

I want to travel to France in June next year but I will also start studying in Italy in September.

So my concern is, can I apply for a tourism visa to France in June? Even though my Italian student visa application would already be processed? 
Since I start in September, the student visa I think will probably be issued in August or around that time but I want to travel in June to France.

Please ask for any clarifications if my question is not clear.

Thanks.

Comment: TL;DR: yes, it's fine. See linked question.